# Changes not reflected by IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, web

I have done some changes(added a button) to Home.aspx page of my vb.net web site.

I have published my website and hosted in IIS.

I could able to see the code for button in my Home.aspx page of my published files.

But when I accessed via URL, I did not get button on my home page.

What could be the issue? I guess the problem would be in IIS. Please suggest some options to try out in IIS.

Comment: Can you see the button in your dev environment? Have you hard refreshed (CTRIL-F5 || CMD-SHIFT-R on a Mac) the page to make sure you're not seeing a browser cached version of the page?

Comment: I can able to see button on running the code through VS. Also I have tried CNTRL+F5. No change

Comment: Can you give us a link to the page in question?

Comment: @Andrew - It would be useless. you can not login

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

While publishing my code in VS, I have unchecked '**Allow this precompiled site to be updated**'